# Get response and raw request when using proxies and resteasy client side framework 3.0.4

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

```
// Some setup steps
ResteasyProviderFactory factory = new ResteasyProviderFactory();
factory.registerProvider(com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider.class);

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfiguration(factory));

WebTarget target = client.target(webappURL.toURI() + "api/v1");
resteasyWebTarget = (ResteasyWebTarget) target;


// the real request
MyApiController myApiController = resteasyWebTarget.proxy(MyApiController.class);
ClientResponse response = (ClientResponse) myApiController.doSomeStuff();
```

The code above works great, but I want to really know what is going on in terms of real http request and real http response when

> myApiController.doSomeStuff();

is executed.

I am wondering what the best way is to catch and log the "raw" request and a catch and log the "raw" http response. I am only interested in solutions for resteasy-client 3.0.2.Final or similar...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to get it if everything went well (response code 200), but in case the server returned anything else, a sub type of ClientErrorException  which gives you access to the response / status code / entity (message body) etc is thrown.

```
try {
    myApiController.doSomeStuff();
} catch (BadRequestException ce) {
    // Handle
} catch (ClientErrorException e) {
     MyErrorObject obj = ce.getResponse().readEntity(MyErrorObject.class);

     // Handle
}
```